# Difference implementing BlocProvider flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, widget, bloc

What's the difference providing to a bloc parameter an object and a class, for example:

```
BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(

bloc: AuthBloc(),

child: Child()

);
```

from:

```
_authBloc = BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context);


BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(

bloc: _authBloc,

child: Child()

);
```

Thanks :), i hope you can help a lot of people with this doubth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Case 1:

BlocProvider(

```
bloc: AuthBloc(),

child: Child()

);
```

In this case, you are creating a new instance of AuthBloc and passing it into the `BlocProvider`.

### Case 2:

```
_authBloc = BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context);


BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(

bloc: _authBloc,

child: Child()

);
```

In this case, you are not creating any new instance, instead fetching the previously created instance from the above tree using `BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context);`

Comment: thanks for the answer. if we create using `BlocBuilder` in the parent , will we be able to gain access to that in the child using `BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context);`?
or we can only access it if it was created using `blocProvider`? 

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should always provide the instance using a blocProvider so that you can access it from anywhere down the tree. BlocBuilder is only useful if you already placed a BlocProvider above the tree.